# How to add an onclick but don't execute href="url" in a <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, href

I want to add an onclick function to an `<a>` tag where the onclick will run and the href won't. I have read that all you need to do is add `return false;` to the onclick function like so:

```html
<a href="https://google.ca" onclick="alert(1); return false;">click here!</a>
```

This should create an alert dialog and not jump to google (or so I've been told), but for me it doesn't show the alert dialog and goes right to google. I have also tried `return true;` but the same thing happened.

The scenario is that a user enters whatever they would like into a textbox (can contain a whitelisted set of HTML tags including `<a>`). After they press enter, it takes them to a new page and the HTML is reflected on this page. I want to see if they can enter a link to a possibly malicious website using the onclick, instead of going to the href.

**EDIT:**

When I inspect the link, this is all that shows up:

```
<a href="https://google.ca" rel="nofollow">click here!</a>
```

Nothing about the onclick function and the alert. Why did it strip out the onclick?

This snippet worked for me as well. It's something to do with the web app I'm using and I'm trying to figure out if there's something that could possibly be blocking this onclick from running

Comment: it works for me!

Comment: Weird, must be something with my application then that's blocking it. Glad to know it works here though!

Comment: To debug, start with only returning false, and see if the button redirects or not.

Comment: it works for me too as  well

Comment: What browser are you testing in? Are you testing on a specific device?

Comment: Depends on the browser/Version/Settings probably.

Comment: @TylerBramer Google Chrome and just A windows 7 pc

Comment: Is it possible that you can filter out javascript functions inside of an html tag? If so someone else may have handled that

Comment: That work for me on Chromium browser version 57.0

Comment: Hmm if you're on a updated version of chrome on desktop then it should work for you (at least in browser here). As far as your application goes, make sure you aren't doing a preventDefault(); on alert actions. Its possible something further down your code is interrupting the default action that should be taking place.

Comment: I just edited the question to be a bit more descriptive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try

`<a href="http://google.com" onclick="alert_func()">`

```
function alert_func(){
    alert(1);
    return false;
}
```